# kendo upload overwrite ul.k-upload-files .k-upload-action style on select event

Tags: jquery, kendo-upload

I have a kendo upload and an external css file wherein the following css has been overwritten:

```
ul.k-upload-files .k-upload-action {
    display: none;
}
```

the reason for the above is not to allow users from removing or cancelling the file during upload. But we also now have some feature wherein we need to show the remove icon once a file has been selected. I have tried getting the specific class during select event of kendo upload but no to avail.

I hope you guys have some ideas how can I solve my issue.

TIA

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue, you can use "success" of kendo upload, below:

```
$("#yourId").kendoUpload({
...
success: onsuccess,
....
})

function onsuccess(x) {
    if (x.operation == "upload") {
        $('.k-upload-action').show();
    }
}
```